# Firebase 9 - Export 'initializeApp' was not found in 'firebase/app'

Tags: javascript, firebase

After upgrading to firebase 9, i am getting trouble importing some functions that used to work on firebase 8. Of course i read the docs and refactored the code but this error keeps popping up, this also happens for other imports.

My imports look like this

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database'
import { getAuth, signInWithCustomToken, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth'
```

The error I get is:

> Export 'initializeApp' was not found in 'firebase/app'

---

I also tried using the compat libraries

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/compat/app'
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/compat/database'
import { getAuth, signInWithCustomToken, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/compat/auth'
```

But i still get

> WARNING "export 'initializeApp' was not found in 'firebase/compat/app'

This also happens for my other imports.

Any help?

Comment: As Dharmaraj explains below, that second error message is expected. In the firs case, the import looks fine though. Can you show how you added a dependency for the SDK for that first example?

Comment: Hi did you find out why the first approach is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compat` version uses the V8 name-spaced syntax and does not require separate imports for every function like in newer modular/functional syntax:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import 'firebase/compat/database'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'

// import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth' <-- Modular version only
```

If you are using `compat` version then make sure you are following the `namespaced` version tab in the documentation:

[image]